# How to find the value of a linear transformation using the matrix representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $L : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation where $L([a_1 \ \ a_2 \ \ a_3]) = [a_1 \ \ a_1 + a_2 \ \ a_1 + a_3]$. Then the matrix representation with respect to the natural basis is

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, I could not understand how to find $L([1 \ -2 \ \ 0])$ using the matrix $A$. I know that $A$ represents the transformation but how can I use the argument $[1 \ -2 \ \ 0]$ with this matrix?

Comment: L(v) = Av (matrix multiplication of A and your vector)

Answer (score 1):

The matrix represent the linear-transformation.

The equation $L(\vec{v})=A\vec{v}$

So:
$$
L(\vec{v})=A\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\vec{v}=\vec{u}$$

And $\vec{u}$ is the new transformed vector.

Comment: Since $A$ is the matrix representation, then $A : \mathbb{R}^3 \to L(v)$ where the vector $v$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So Av = Lv. Is this logical?

Comment: Think abou $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\vec{v}$$ as $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2 \\
    v_3
\end{pmatrix}$$ which equals $$\begin{pmatrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_1+v_2 \\
    v_1+v_3 
\end{pmatrix}$$ and that's the vector representation of L